# AWS Codebuild Compile .net 4 project

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2015, aws-codebuild, build-tools

I need to build a C# winforms project using aws codebuild. This is my buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo "Installing DotNet 4.8"
      - Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/014120d7-d689-4305-befd-3cb711108212/0307177e14752e359fde5423ab583e43/ndp48-devpack-enu.exe -OutFile C:\ndp48-devpack-enu.exe
      - Start-Process C:\ndp48-devpack-enu.exe -ArgumentList "/quiet /norestart /log C:\dn48.txt" -wait
      - cat C:\dn48.txt
      - echo "Installing Windows SDK"
      - Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/c/3/1c3d5161-d9e9-4e4b-9b43-b70fe8be268c/windowssdk/winsdksetup.exe -OutFile C:\winsdksetup.exe
      - Start-Process C:\winsdksetup.exe -ArgumentList "/quiet /norestart /log C:\wsdk.txt" -wait
      - cat C:\wsdk.txt
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Building application"
      - msbuild v14 build....
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build complete
```

I am using aws codebuild windows-base:2.0. All the installations pass but when I try to build I get `Task failed because "AxImp.exe" was not found` although I did install windows 10 SDK

Anyone has any idea how to make it work? doesn't even have to be the above solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this great guide from amazon

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/creating-ci-cd-pipelines-for-asp-net-4-x-with-aws-codepipeline-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk/